# SQL - Returning a number of rows using a sub-query

Tags: sql, join, subquery

I can't quite get my head around this one so I need some advice please.

I have a number of products to which I have assigned some keywords using separate tables. I would like to iterate through those keywords and produce a list of other products that contain the same keyword... So in the example below I have a product with the ID of 149 that has two keywords assigned to it, however my SQL will only work on a product with one keyword.

So the bit I can't quite get my head around is how I can produce a list of products utilising both keywords. Any help would be great.

SQL:-

```
 $products_id = $_GET['products_id'];
 $slideQuery = mysql_query("

 select p.products_id, p.products_image, p.products_price, 
 pd.products_name, k2p.key_key_id  

 from products p

 join products_description pd on 
 pd.products_id = p.products_id 

 join products_keyword_to_product k2p on 
 k2p.products_id = p.products_id 

 where k2p.key_key_id = (
      select key_key_id  
  from
  products_keyword_to_product
  where 
  products_id=" . $products_id ."
      )  

  group by p.products_id 
  order by p.products_price desc 
  limit 12
```

Edit to add: I have achieved this before by using a php while loop and querying the database within this loop, but I'm convinced that there has to be a better way of doing this.

Update: I looked into the suggestions I received from this question and could never quite get my query to work. At this point it's a little beyond my 'pay grade' so I chose to create a link that would pass the relevant IDs into the URL string and re-load the page which as the site grows will probably turn out to be the better option anyway.
I think the lesson learned here is to step back from what you're trying to achieve and ensure that the way you are doing it is the best way to achieve it.

Comment: Your problem is MySQL's shoddy handling of GROUP BY. If you learn how it should work, that will help you write queries correctly, which will then give you the results you want.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to do this with GROUP BY and HAVING.

```
select p.products_id,
    p.products_image,
    p.products_price,
    pd.products_name,
    k2p.key_key_id
from products p
inner join (
    select products_id
    from products_keyword_to_product
    where key_key_id in (
        select key_key_id
        from products_keyword_to_product
        where products_id = " . $products_id ."
    )
    group by products_id
    having count(distinct key_key_id) = (
        select count(distinct key_key_id)
        from products_keyword_to_product
        where products_id = " . $products_id ."
    )
) pm on p.products_id = pm.products_id
inner join products_keyword_to_product k2p on k2p.products_id = p.products_id
inner join products_description pd on pd.products_id = p.products_id
order by p.products_price desc 
limit 12
```

Comment: Running this through Mysql returns error "Unknown column 'p.products_id' in 'group statement'", so I don't know if it would otherwise work, however I hadn't considered using sub queries within an inner join so even if I don't get a working answer from this post I will have something that I can play with.

Comment: You expect a perfect query with no schema or sample data provided? Would you be able to do that? I have modified the query according to the error message, but if you provide a schema and sample data I may give you a *working* query.

Comment: So you have - Thanks for that. It doesn't return the results I was expecting but it's hard to come up with something that would without having direct access to the data. I thank you for your answer and the direction that you have pointed me in.
ETA. Just saw your comment, I guess we are both thinking along the same lines. I wouldn't ask more of you than what you can give with the data provided to you :) ETA2 - I hope you are not offended.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `IN` instead of `=`

ie:

```
 ....
 where k2p.key_key_id IN ( 
 ....
```

Comment: This worked in as much as the product in question now displays results for key_key_id of 39 // First keyword, but doesn't show key_key_id 54 //second keyword - But if worst comes to worst I will have least have a set of results, thanks :)

Comment: Have a look at `Group_concat`